# 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs...-react native

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, ffmpeg

I am trying to enable package of [ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native) in react-native.
The sample commands given in the [example](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native#3-using) executes successfully. But I want to use `libwebp` for converting gif files to webp which is under [package](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit#8-packages) named `video`. As [instrcuted](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native#221-enabling-a-package-on-android) . I have to enable the [package](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit#8-packages) to use some libraries.

> 2.2.1 Enabling a Package on Android
> Edit android/build.gradle file and add the package name in ext.ffmpegKitPackage variable.
>
> ```java
> ext {
>    ffmpegKitPackage = "<package name>"
> }
> ```

So I added a line in the `node_module/ffmpeg-kit-react-native/android/build.gradle`

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 30

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion safeExtGet('ffmpegKitPackage', 'https').contains("-lts") ? 16 : 24
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 451
    versionName "4.5.1"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    disable 'GradleCompatible'
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  rootProject.ext.ffmpegKitPackage = "video" // Added this line here 

}
```

Error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7403ebe5571a2ce5a6a5fc9876af4814\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.66.4\jni
      - C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4be54e44fe38656741a8345504588323\transformed\jetified-ffmpeg-kit-video-4.5.1-1\jni
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets
```

I have tried ./gradlew clean but problem is still there.
How to fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

add this in your `node_module/ffmpeg-kit-react-native/android/build.gradle`

```kotlin
android{
  packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
  }
  rootProject.ext.ffmpegKitPackage = "video"
}
```

ffmpeg-kit-react-native has already talked about this error here. https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Tips#2-depending-another-android-library-containing-libc_sharedso

Comment: also try to add this inmain app's gradle

Comment: This is not clean at all, since when you will install any module this will be wiped away. Prefer @Leandro Ariel answer

Comment: both answers are same . why do you think that's it is not clean and should prefer other answer over this answer.

Comment: @TOPKAT one way to get around the issue of having them wiped out is to use patch-package which allows you to always apply a git patch to a node_module when it is installed.

Comment: @CrackerKSR it's not recommended at all to modify `node_modules` directly, I agree that it's also not recommended to write in android/ios folder too if you are using expo for example, but there is less chances to see android/ios folder wiped out than node_modules

Comment: @TOPKAT yes right, and I commented that too as I could not edit. :) i initially tried inside the module's gradle and it worked to posted the answer but the better way is to adding the code in app level gradle of project.

Comment: Just adding that you don't need to list all the abis separately, but instead you can use one line: `pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'`

Answer (score 45):

I'm using **react native 0.68.2** and my issue has been fixed by applying the following changes.

edit `android/build.gradle` and force all modules to use the same react-native version as your project.

```
allprojects {
    
    // ...

    def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

you can check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204) for more information

Comment: This is required solution. Other related issues also went away after this

Comment: Thanks Ahmad - this worked for us with RN 0.71.0.

Answer (score 36):

You need to add in your build.gradle(app) this:

```
android {
    //2 files found for path lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so. This version of the Android Gradle Plugin chooses the f
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
```

This works for me. In react 0.68.2. And 0.69.x.

Comment: Working with React-Native 0.70 too

Comment: Worked with 0.67.4

Comment: Worked for me in NativeScript 8.5.3, thanks. Added those lines to PROJECT/App_Resources/android/app.gradle

Answer (score 6):

```
android{
  packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
  }
  rootProject.ext.ffmpegKitPackage = "video"
}
```

//if not working above than try below code

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```